# Restore S-Memo files

Tags: backup, samsung-galaxy-s-4, s-memo

A few days ago my Samsung Galaxy S4 asked to uodate the Samsung Account application which I accepted. After that all me S-Memo files are gone. They aren't in me SD-Card/S-Memo folder. And when I open S-Memo and choose import I can't choose Samsung account. The Memo's are still on my Samsung backup account. When I go to settings/account/samsung/used storage I see 2.85 mb of S-Memo files. When I click on that it asks me which files I want to delete but I don't want to delete them. I want them back. When I go to the account tab in settings again there's a option called cloud with which I can restore files from the Samsung cloud but I only can choose between, logfiles, mms, sms and wallpapers. I definitely need the memo files back. Does anybody knows how I can get them back from the Samsung server. Luckily they aren't completely lost. 
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but i just updated my phone software and lost my SMemo's. Dont know how many other people would still be updating old software but in any case, here's where I found them on my phone:
My Files>Application>SMemo>Switcher

Also, when i connected my laptop to the phone they could be found in:
Phone>Application>SMemo>Switcher